# Circle radius touching 3 lines

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: Circle Diagram]

I'd like to know how to work out the radius of the pink circle. The angle between the radial lines of the big circle is $60^\circ$. The big circle has radius $x$. The pink circle sits on the radial lines and the big circle.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange - have you attempted anything yet? Showing what you have already done can help people write answers at the right level for your knowledge

Comment: Note that you can fit 3 pink circles in the big circle, and they will all touch.

Comment: Use Kiss precise formula

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Let $R$ be the bigger radius and $r$ the smaller one. Draw the radius in the smaller circle from the center to one of the tangent points. Show that
$(R-r)\sin(60^{\circ})=r$. Finally find $r$.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense, didn't think about the distance between the centers being R-r. So:
r = R(sin(60º)) / 1 + Sin(60º)